# Time-varying coefficients in coxph

Tags: regression, survival, regression-coefficients, cox-model

I'm trying to understand time-varying coefficients in `survival::coxph` and the `tt` notation. I found [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6015946/), which clarified some of my questions and provided the example below.

The way I understand it, we can interact a covariate $X$ with some function of time $g(t)$ and then have a constant coefficient to represent this new time-varying covariate $\tilde{X} = Xg(t)$ instead of having an actual time-varying coefficient for $X$. However, if that were true, I would expect to get the same result from these two models below.

```
library(survival)
fit.tt <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.karno + tt(ph.karno),
                data=lung, 
                tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t + 20))
summary(fit.tt)

fit.I <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.karno + I(ph.karno*log(time + 20)),
               data=lung)
summary(fit.I)
```

Why do these two formulas yield such different results or how is my intuition wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.2 of the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) of the R survival package discusses the problem with your second model:

> The issue is that the above code does not actually create a time dependent covariate, rather it creates a time-static value for each subject based on their value for the covariate `time`; no differently than if we had constructed the variable outside of a coxph call. This variable most definitely breaks the rule about not looking into the future, and one would quickly find the circularity: large values of `time` appear to predict long survival because long survival leads to large values for `time`.

In your second model, the `time` variable used in your interaction is exactly (and only) the event or censoring time for an individual. So that doesn't generate a continuous function of time, as you seek. That interaction term is just a single, fixed value for each individual.

The first model instead defines a new `tt()` continuous function of time. While the software runs through all the event times in fitting the Cox model, that generates a new value of the interaction term, specific to that elapsed time `t`, for all individuals still at risk.

To summarize: `time` in the second model refers to a fixed covariate value for each individual; the `t` in the first model represents a value that changes in the way that you want.